# Not able to render the ListItem in React-native elements

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to render some of items in the ListItem in React-native.
This is my data:

```
[
    {
        "meetingname": "Jithin",
        "meetingcreatedon": [
            "May 02 2019 10:16:24"
        ],
        "meetingstatus": "ontime",
        "meetingcreatedby": "qvgahjvdsg",
        "meetingparticipants": "",
        "meetingid": "tyxasirhunxirty",
        "meetingtime": "2012-00-20 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "meetingname": "Jithin",
        "meetingcreatedon": [
            "May 02 2019 10:16:24"
        ],
        "meetingstatus": "ontime",
        "meetingcreatedby": "qvgahjvdsg",
        "meetingparticipants": "",
        "meetingid": "tyxasirhunxirty",
        "meetingtime": "2012-00-20 00:00:00"
    }
]
```

And this is my function for rendering the list item

```
componentDidMount(){
        getAllMeetingService().then(data=> {
            this.meetingData.push(data[0]);
            Alert.alert(typeof this.meetingData)
            Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(this.meetingData));
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <OfflineNotice />
                {
                    this.meetingData.map((meeting, i)=>(
                        <ListItem
                        key= {i}
                        title= {meeting.meetingname}
                        subtitle= {meeting.meetingtime}
                        ></ListItem>
                    ))
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
```

But nothing seems to render the Listitem. I have tried with the some dummy values, which is able to render?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try doing `console.log(this.meetingData)` inside `render` (before `return`). What happens?

Comment: Ohh.. This just returned []

Comment: So are you sure you're getting the result from your function back?

Comment: Yes in the alert method I am able to get the data. But it is not rendering in the component

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I am able to resolve it. I made a setState and, it got rendered